# Chroot into a 32-bit version of Ubuntu from a 64-bit host

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, chroot

Xilinx webPack 10.1 requires 32-bit Linux. <sub>Only this old version is compatible with their boards.</sub> [How to make 32-bit applications work on a 64-bit operating system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#How_to_Make_32-bit_Applications_Work_on_a_64-bit_Operating_System) lists:

1. Installation of 32-bit compatibility libraries (ia32-libs or Multiarch support)
   <sub>I already installed ia32-libs, and it's still not working</sub>
2. A 32-bit [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot)
3. Full virtualization through KVM or VirtualBox <sub>No, I don't want to be working from a vm all of next semester, that would be painful and I'd rather just reinstall my whole computer to a 32 bit os; which I don't want to do.</sub>
4. Another option in a pinch is getlibs getlibs <sub>It didn't sound like it was the best option based on what I've seen.</sub>

So I went off to do #2, and set up a chroot for 32-bit Ubuntu Lucid (10.10). Which is to say I wrote:

```
[hardy-i386]
description=Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy for i386
directory=/srv/chroot/hardy-i386
personality=linux32
root-users=leif
type=directory
users=leif
```

to

```
/etc/schroot/chroot.d/hardy-i386
```

I then ran:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/hardy_i386
$ sudo debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch i386 hardy /srv/chroot/hardy_i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

Then I ran:

```
$ schroot -l
```

And it showed the proper chroot, but then when I run:

```
$ schroot -c hardy-i386 -u root
```

I get the following error:

```
E: 10mount: error: Directory '/srv/chroot/hardy-i386' does not exist
E: 10mount: warning: Mount location /var/lib/schroot/mount/hardy-i386-80359697-2164-4b10-a05a-89b0f497c4f1 no longer exists; skipping unmount
E: hardy-i386-80359697-2164-4b10-a05a-89b0f497c4f1: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-start
```

`/srv/chroot/hardy-i386` most certainly exists. I've also tried it replacing all references with hardy to lucid, to no avail. I did set up the chrome os environment: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide and it had me use something with `chmod`.

So, can anyone figure out what the problem is?

Comment: I'd back up a little. What error are you getting when you try to run the application? Most cross-arch software issues I've seen can be solved with `getlibs`

Comment: Here is what I get:leif@leif-VPCEB11FM:~/Downloads/webpack$ ./setup
Product is not supported on "Linux x86_64" platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may try

```
linux32 ./setup
```

this helps for 32Bit teamspeak on 64bit servers.

from man: (linux32 is an setarch alias)

```
   setarch  -  change reported architecture in new program environment and
   set personality flags
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo on your instructions, on /etc/schroot/chroot.d/hardy-i386 you are using /srv/chroot/hardy-i386 , while for the mkdir/debootstrap you are using hardy_i386 for the directory. That explains the error.

I have just fixed the path at /etc/schroot/chroot.d/hardy-i386, tested, it worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  Fixing that, everything worked fine.  I need to look into updating the documentation now.