# How do I re-install or delete 64-bit 12.10 and install 32-bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I’m a new user to Linux and so I used the automatic Windows dual boot installer and it installed Ubuntu 64-bit 12.10 on my XP computer. But some of the Xilinx programs I need to run require 32-bit. So I need to either re-install or delete it and start over.

I've created a clean 32-bit Ubuntu install DVD but when I run it, it doesn't recognize that I already have a 64-bit version of Ubuntu installed so it doesn't give me a way to delete it. There is the `other` option that should allow me to delete the partition but it doesn't show an Ubuntu partition, just a 150M Windows partition.

I don't care about anything in the Ubuntu directories so a full erase is okay. I can't seem to find any description on the web that match my problem so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The installation was done via Wubi?

Comment: As it usually should be no problem to run 32-bit applications in a 64-bit Ubuntu you also may want to consider rewording you question like e.g. *"How do I install Xilinx <specific name of application> in a 64-bit Ubuntu"* (press [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/243602/edit) to do so). Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/20554/chroot-into-a-32-bit-version-of-ubuntu-from-a-64-bit-host

Answer (score 0):

If you're running 64-bit ubuntu, you can choose to run either 32-bit mongo or 64-bit mongo, as [takkat](https://askubuntu.com/users/3940/takkat) mentioned. (a 32-bit OS would force you to use only the 32-bit executable.)

Personally, I find it simpler and more predictable to just go to the [10gen distributions page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads), and download and untar the version I want.  After that, executing the right `bin/mongod` just works right out of the box.